# Non-selective query against large object type (more than 100000 rows) - Contacts

Tags: soql

I am running into a problem with an org that has a very large number of contacts. New contacts are created, or existing one are updated based on orders that come in via a REST interface. All was working well until yesterday, when we began receiving non-selective query errors. I understand this is occurring because the contacts table contains more than 100,000 rows now, but I am unsure how to remedy this error. The following is the query used to match pre-existing contacts, and also the source of the error.

```
    List<Contact> ExistingContacts = [SELECT Id,
                                      npe01__HomeEmail__c,
                                      npe01__AlternateEmail__c,
                                      email,
                                      npe01__WorkEmail__c,
                                      Alternate_Email_2__c,
                                      Alternate_Email_3__c
                                      FROM Contact 
                                      WHERE
                                      (npe01__HomeEmail__c IN :OrderEmailAddresses OR
                                      npe01__AlternateEmail__c IN :OrderEmailAddresses OR
                                      email IN :OrderEmailAddresses OR
                                      Alternate_Email_2__c IN :OrderEmailAddresses OR
                                      Alternate_Email_3__c IN :OrderEmailAddresses OR
                                      npe01__WorkEmail__c IN :OrderEmailAddresses)
                                      ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC];
```

We have discussed creating another custom field that contains a comma separated list based on all the email fields, and setting it as a unique identifier, but that seems like a round about way to try and tackle this problem. Have anyone dealt with this before, and if so can you please off some help!

Answer (score 5):

You need indexes for all of the fields you're using if you're going to use SOQL. This means that they must all be marked as External ID or have custom indexes created.

Failing that, you may want to use SOSL, because the search indexer (not to be confused with a database index) will include all of the email fields in the search.

Example:

```
FIND :email IN EMAIL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Id, npe01__HomeEmail__c, npe01__AlternateEmail__c, email, npe01__WorkEmail__c, Alternate_Email_2__c, Alternate_Email_3__c)
```

You can also use multiple statements in a search term. See the [FIND {searchTerm}](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm) page for details.